# Show live id used in developer licence in windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-store

I have genreated the developer license and installed on my windows 8 machine succesfully using a newly created live account. 
Is there any way to view the live id used in the installed developer license in a machine?

I have used ' Get-WindowsDeveloperLicense' command, but it is showing only the license expiration date . I want to see the live id / user id that was used in generating the license.

Any help.??

Comment: vs 2012 express -> help -> about dialog shows the name of the licensed user in right corner.

Comment: @Sushil No, that info is about the user to which visual studio is licensed. I want to get the details about the developer license used in developeing windows store apps.

Comment: afaik, there is not such license installed. I access [this link](https://appdev.microsoft.com/StorePortals/en-us/Home/Index?wa=wsignin1.0), sign in and get to know app registered/published by my live id. I do not install any license as much on the machine. may be I am missing something.

Comment: Try executing the cmd Get-WindowsDeveloperLicense. Yuo will see the expiration date for thedeveloper license. One has to renew the license every 30 days.

Comment: you can use vs 2012 `store->acquire dev license` or `Show-WindowsDeveloperLicenseRegistration` which should go through the flow of renewing the license. may be that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other PowerShell Command except Get-WindowsDeveloperLicense which will give you any details about the developer license.

Get-Command will list all the Shell commands but none of the command will give you required details.